# How to use setDisplay() for a mediaplayer in service class where surfaceView is made in the activity class?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-mediaplayer

In my activity class I have set the surfaceview like this:

```
surfaceView =(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
```

Now I want to set the display for the mediaplayer which I have created and started in the service class as I want it to run in the background even though any person is not interacting with the activity. I want to use the following code in the service class but how can I use the surfaceView declared in activity in the service as it cant be passed through intent.putExtra() from activity to service.

```
mMediaPlayer.reset();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder());
```

Comment: Try another way around. Get the media player object from the service in your activity and add the surfaceview holder to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Bind to the `Service` from the `Activity`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) so that you have an instance of your `Service`. Create a method that returns your instance of `MediaPlayer` from the `Service`. The rest should be obvious, I believe. Just ask if there's anything that doesn't make sense.